# Laravel Unique Validation Based on Multiple Column Data Value

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

[image: Image of Database]

In this scenario , My Phone number will be unique based on my `domain_id`. Phone number can be multiple in phone columns but its obvioulsy would be depend on domain_id column.

Example: 01303062727 This Numbers are two times is phone column but they have different domain_id value.

How can be validate this rules ?

Comment: Can't you just pull up the database with the phone number in question, before inserting it into the database, and either accept or reject it based on the result?

Comment: Actually I'm doing this right now! @KevinY

Comment: Just create a custom validation rule (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules), and do your logic here. What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Somehow, I solve this problem by doing this,
 Rule::unique('customers', 'phone')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('phone', $this->phone)
                        ->where('domain_id', request()->get('domain_id'));
                })->ignore($this->id)

Answer (score 3):

here you can take advantage of unique rule that laravel provides.
your code would be something like this :

```
'phone_number' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('domain_id', $domain_id);
})
```

obviously you may pass $domain_id variable along with your inputs or any other way you want . this code will scopes the query to make rule of uniqueness only toward records that have domain_id of a specific value. so repeated number will be allowed but for different domain ids

Comment: Yes, I did this in way. @AlirezaSalehi
`Rule::unique('customers', 'phone')->where(function ($query) { $query->where('phone', $this->phone) ->where('domain_id', request()->get('domain_id')); })->ignore($this->id)`